# Emojis and Special Characters not rendering on Subject Header in Pug using Sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, sendgrid

Please the issue is that any emoji or special character are not rendering on the subject header of the pug file. but working perfectly on the body. I compile both body and subject header differently using pug.

```
const compileHtmlFunction = pug.compileFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../emails", templatePath, "html.pug")
  );



const getSubjectFunction = pug.compileFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../emails", templatePath, "subject.pug")
  );

const payload = {


  DestinationEmail: to,
    SourceEmail: fromEmail ? `Switch By Sterling ${fromEmail}` : "Switch By Sterling team@switch-ng.com",
    Body: compileHtmlFunction(data),
    Subject: getSubjectFunction(data)
  };
```

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""html.pug

```
doctype html
include ../../layouts/header

div(style='display: none; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden;')
div(style='background-color: #ecedfa; line-height: 30px; padding-top:5px;')
  div(style='background-color: #ffffff; color: #484347;  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 100px; max-width: 400px; padding: 20px;')
    div 
      center 
        img(src='https://res.cloudinary.com/dzkyrqr5e/image/upload/v1648553921/new-headers/password-reset_ait4kd.png' alt='' width='100%' height="100%" border='0' style='display: block; margin: 20px auto 20px auto;')
    p(style='margin: 0 0 5px 0;')
      | Hello #{first_name},
      br
      | You are receiving this email because there has been a password change request on your account.
      | If you initiated this request, please change your password by clicking the 'Change my password' button below. The link will expire after 10 minutes.
      br
      a(href=updatePasswordUrl) Change my password
      br
      | If you didn't request this, please ignore this email. Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.
      br
      p(style='margin: 0') With &#128156;
      | Your friends at Switch

    include ../../layouts/footer_image
```

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""subject.pug

```
| Launch  &#128156;
```

Comment: Can you share the (relevant parts of) the `.pug` files as well?

Comment: done...but the emoji is not rendering on the subject.pug it renders the hexadecimal code

Answer (score 0):

The subject line of an email isn't rendered like an HTML file, so I don't think you want to escape the emoji in the subject.

Try changing your subject.pug file to:

```
| Launch
```

Comment: The emoji is not rendering too...it does not compile and i dont receive message whenever i dont escape the emoji

Comment: I've just installed pug, created a template with that exact text in, including the emoji, and it compiles and the email is sent. You've tagged this question "sendgrid" but the `payload` you create is different to the SendGrid Node library. Are you using SendGrid and can you see the email in your [SendGrid activity dashboard](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity)?